# Launch an application using Advanced Installer

Tags: advanced-installer

I have developed an installer using Advanced Installer.**I have a GUI which is a .exe file which I want to launch after the execution completes.**

**I tried adding the .exe to post installation but the .exe is launched midway when the installation has not finished and when  I close the GUI button the installation completes.**
I want that when the installation is complete,the GUI(.exe) file should be launched

**I also want that on the click of launch application button at the end of the installation should launch the GUI**

**When I click the launch application button it opens the folder SYSWOW64**

I found few solutions to this,I tried all of them but nothing seems to be working for me at the moment.

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a custom action, right? So if it runs too early, why can't you just sequence it later, maybe after InstallFinalize.

Do you need a button to say launch it? Why not just run it?

Comment: Thanks @PhilDW.Ya it would be better to launch the application without a button after the installation completes.How to achieve this.What's install Finalize? where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to [launch the application at the end of the installation](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-application.html) using Advanced Installer. The article I linked explains all of them.

Comment: I had read about this article @Bordgan Mitrache and i have even mentioned it in my question above.but nothing seems to be working.Would you please explain what is to be done? Thanks